# Where can I find a stack trace for crashing dotnet app on macOS?

Tags: macos, .net-core

I have an Avalonia application built with .NET 7, that I have compiled for macOS and bundled to a .app.

It's beta so there are issues. If it crashes, on Windows I can simply tell my testers to go event viewer and retreieve the managed .NET stack trace, however I am struggling to find out where to find this on macOS. I can easily find the native crash logs on the system, but they do little to nothing to help me figure out what's actually happening.